# Turbolinks and Ruby Shopify_app 20.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app, turbolinks

My shopify app uses shopify_app 19 and turbolinks to load the code into the embedded app:

```
Turbolinks.visit(data.loadPath);
```

Until today, I just needed to add the session value in the header:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppBridge.sessionToken);
```

But after I upgraded to the new 20.1.0 version, nothing is working. Looking into the code:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/main/lib/shopify_app/controller_concerns/login_protection.rb#L222

apparently now the app is expecting that I must send the "session":

```
params[:session].present?
```

and "shop" params (values) on each single request. But I don't know how to do that with Turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

When you say nothing is working what exactly is happening? What error are you getting?
Are you initializing AppBridge with api key and host?

```
createApp({
    apiKey: apiKey,
    host: host,
  });
```